# Banished resolution & mouse issues

Tags: technical-issues, banished

I want to play [Banished](http://store.steampowered.com/app/242920/).

I have a Macbook Pro Retina display, and am running  Windows 7 on Boot Camp.

I have installed the game (not with Steam), and the first thing I noticed was that the resolution was all wrong (the game objects were larger than they should be). So I went to settings and set the resolution to 2880x1800, and the display is now fine.

However, the mouse is not fine. If you put the mouse over an interface button, you can't click it. Instead, you have to move the mouse further diagonally to the bottom-right slowly - eventually, the button will highlight (despite the mouse being far away from it) and you can click it.

So I need to solve this mouse issue. I exited the game and entered back in, and noticed that the settings had reset (the resolution was wrong again!).

---

I searched the web, and there is a number of things to try:

**Disable DirectX 11**. You can do this by modifying the Windows registry as explained here: http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Troubleshooting. With this done, the resolution is fine.

However, with this comes a new issue. I can see the mouse cursor, **but I can't move it**.

Searching further, it seems to have worked for someone who disabled fullscreen. So I did this. But the mouse still won't move.

I'm not sure what to do now.

---

My Macbook has the BootCamp drivers installed alright, and it is using an Iris graphic card thing.

I also tried changing the resolution to 1440x900 both in the game and in my desktop properties. Same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should avoid using the game menu to change the settings (at least the first time you play the game). Using the Windows registry, change

- `VideoFullscreen` to `false`
- `VideoInterface` to `0`

After that, the mouse should work fine. And once you got that working, you'll be able to use the game menu to change the settings without problem.

Weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by switching from DirectX 9 to DirectX 11.

You can do this in the in-game menu: Menu -> Options -> Video